# javascript not modifying style properties sequentially

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a photo gallery using fade functions. I've gone through many so lets use [this one](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/01/javascript-fade-in-out/) as an example.

I've been trying to get my code to work in IE 8 where the amount of stacked images with `opacity:0` makes the animations laggy (single images fade smoothly). What solves this problem is to do `display:none` on the image after its faded out. The problem that arises now is that my images disappear instantly and not after the finished animation. Is there a way to fix this?

My modified demo code:

```
<div class="button" onclick="

    if(boole)
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display = '';

    fadeEffect.init('fade', boole?1:0);

if(!boole)
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'none';

    boole = !boole;

">Fade In</div>
```

Comment: You won't be able to do it with that fade effect code. You'll need one that allows you to pass in a callback, or else you'll need to modify that one to allow it.

Comment: I cried looking at your inline code

Comment: @Pointy So I put an `alert("foo")` just after `clearInterval(this.si);` and it runs after the animation. When I put a display:none there my shits disapper instantly. So how does this problem relate to callbacks?

Comment: The fade effect code is doing its work through a series of timers. If it provided a way for you to pass in a "do this when finished" callback then you could but your style update code in that callback. As it is, your call to the "init" method just *starts* the fade process, but it will complete in successive steps quite a long while after the next statement after the "init" call is executed.

Comment: @Pointy Yes I understand this. My question is why does `alert("foo")` run after the animation but the display property gets modifed instantly.

Comment: In the "tween" function, that call to "clearInterval()" happens *after* the animation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's providing that fadeEffect function, but most JS effects libraries have callback capabilities - calling a function when the effect completes. If fadeEffect has such a capability, you'd put the `display: none` stuff into that callback function. When the effect completes, the callback function is invoked, and off you go.